# How to easily convert IndexedSeq[Array[Int]] to Seq[Seq[Int]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, type-conversion

I have a function that takes a list of lists of integer, specifically `Seq[Seq[Int]]`. Then I produce this data from reading a text file and using `split`, and that produces a list of `Array`. That is not recognized by Scala, who raises a match error. But either `IndexedSeq` or `Array` alone are OK with a `Seq[Int]` function, apparently only the nested collection is an issue. How can I convert implicitly `IndexedSeq[Array[Int]]` to `Seq[Seq[Int]]`, or how else could I do this other than using `toList` as demonstrated below? `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]` seems to be fine, for instance, but I can't use this.

```
scala> def g(x:Seq[Int]) = x.sum
g: (x: Seq[Int])Int

scala> g("1 2 3".split(" ").map(_.toInt))
res6: Int = 6

scala> def f(x:Seq[Seq[Int]]) = x.map(_.sum).sum
f: (x: Seq[Seq[Int]])Int

scala> f(List("1 2 3", "3 4 5").map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt)))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Array[Int]]
 required: Seq[Seq[Int]]
              f(List("1 2 3", "3 4 5").map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt)))
                                          ^

scala> f(List("1 2 3", "3 4 5").map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList))
res8: Int = 18
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I think this has more to do with immutable vs mutable collections than anything else.

Comment: Note how `f(List("1,2,3".split(",").map(_.toInt), "1,2,3".split(",").map(_.toInt)))` actually works ...

Comment: Crazy thing, if you _assign_  this and pass the value as a parameter, it doesn't work. But if you inline this expression in the function call, it works!!?? I guess that by breaking the first map and running the expression inside the function call the type inference and default implicit conversions can work their magic, but not otherwise... I don't think I have ever seen an example of something like that before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Array` does not implement `SeqLike`. Normally, implicit conversions to `ArrayOps` or `WrappedArray` defined in `scala.predef` allow to use array just like `Seq`. However, in your case array is 'hidden' from implicit conversions as a generic argument. One solution would be to hint compiler that you can apply an implicit conversion to the generic argument like this:

```
def f[C <% Seq[Int]](x:Seq[C]) = x.map(_.sum).sum
```

This is similar to Paul's response above. The problem is that view bounds are deprecated in Scala 2.11 and using deprecated language features is not a good idea. Luckily, view bounds can be rewritten as context bounds as follows:

```
 def f[C](x:Seq[C])(implicit conv: C => Seq[Int]) = x.map(_.sum).sum
```

Now, this assumes that there is an implicit conversion from `C` to `Seq[Int]`, which is indeed present in predef.

Comment: Now this is what I was looking for. So if I understand correctly, normally `Array` can be passed to a `Seq`, and we don't even care about the implicit conversion (it is _really_ implicit). But when it gets inside a container the compiler doesn't know what to do, and we need to give a hand so it can apply the usual conversion, and we get a WrappedArray. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
implicit def _convert(b:List[Array[Int]]):Seq[Seq[Int]]=b.map(_.toList)
```

Comment: Well, kudos for writing us down the implicit conversion code, since it should be useful. I actually ended up using `def fun[T](xx: Traversable[Seq[T]]) = xx map (_.reverse)` and `implicit def _convert[T](b: Traversable[Array[T]]): Traversable[Seq[T]] = b.map(_.toVector)`. But in my question was hoping to completely avoid the `toList`, even implicitly...

Comment: If you just replace the `_.toList` with the creation of a `WrappedArray` from the input `Array`, than it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine f to be a bit more flexible.

Since [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) is a parent of List, Seq, Array, etc., f will be compatible with these containers if it based on Traversable.  Traversable has sum, flatten, and map, and that is all that's needed.

What is tricky about this is that

```
def f(y:Traversable[Traversable[Int]]):Int = y.flatten.sum
```

is finicky and doesn't work on a y of type `List[Array[Int]]` although it will work on `Array[List[Int]]`

To make it less finicky, some type view bounds will work.

Initially, I replaced your sum of sums with a flatten/sum operation.

```
def f[Y<%Traversable[K],K<%Traversable[Int]](y:Y):Int=y.flatten.sum
```

I found this also seems to work but I did not test as much:

```
def f[Y <% Traversable[K], K <% Traversable[Int]](y:Y):Int=y.map(_.sum).sum
```

This `<%` syntax says Y is [viewable](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#viewbounds) as Traversable[K] for some type K that is viewable as a Traversable of Int.

Define some different containers, including the one you need:

```
scala> val myListOfArray = List(Array(1,2,3),Array(3,4,5))
val myListOfArray = List(Array(1,2,3),Array(3,4,5))
myListOfArray: List[Array[Int]] = List(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(3, 4, 5))

scala> val myArrayOfList = Array(List(1,2,3),List(3,4,5))
val myArrayOfList = Array(List(1,2,3),List(3,4,5))
myArrayOfList: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 4, 5))

scala> val myListOfList = List(List(1,2,3),List(3,4,5))
val myListOfList = List(List(1,2,3),List(3,4,5))
myListOfList: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 4, 5))

scala> val myListOfRange = List(1 to 3, 3 to 5)
val myListOfRange = List(1 to 3, 3 to 5)
myListOfRange: List[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = List(Range(1, 2, 3), Range(3, 4, 5))
```

Test:

```
scala> f(myListOfArray)
f(myListOfArray)
res24: Int = 18

scala> f(myArrayOfList)
f(myArrayOfList)
res25: Int = 18

scala> f(myListOfList)
f(myListOfList)
res26: Int = 18

scala> f(myListOfRange)
f(myListOfRange)
res28: Int = 18
```

Comment: FYI, view bounds are deprecated: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629 . You're supposed to use implicit parameters instead, according to this tread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/hNow9MvAi6Q/discussion

Comment: @Tim Interesting read, a majority for deprecation and a few stragglers who say view bounds will improve and be kept, among other gems.  I'm just beginning to learn a bit of the more complex parts of scala, and the unsettled portions and syntax changes aren't exactly enticing.  Happy to play with it as a kind of puzzle but the interest might end there...

Comment: From that discussion I felt that decision to deprecate view bounds is unequivocal, although it won't really happen until 2.14 or so. Above, I have provided another answer that does 'unsugaring' of % symbol, if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great suggestion, and I had actually tried it. But as it always happens to me, the simpler example I bring here ends up being too simple. In my actual application I need `def fun[T](xx: Seq[Seq[T]]) = xx map (_.reverse)`, and `Traversable` has no `reverse`. So I guess I really need the conversion somewhere. But it's good to learn that `Seq` is actually more specific than `Traversable`, and is probably what you should be using whenever possible.